# defn vs. let with regards to decomposition

Tags: clojure

I define a function, which takes two parameters - map and a key. The key is referenced from the map parameter decomposition

```
(defn myfunc [{v k} k]
   v)
```

when I call:

```
  (myfunc {:a 10} :a)
```

It surprisingly produces expected result: 10

Similar thing in the let:

```
(let [{v k} {:a 10} k :a] v)
```

fails, because *k* is not defined at the moment, when first part is evaluated.

My question is: why decomposition inside function parameters behaves differently compared to decomposition in *let* expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macroexpanding the `defn` form I get the equivalent of this (removed .withMeta stuff and reformatted):

```
(def myfunc
  (fn* myfunc
       ([p__11393 k]
          (let* [map__11394 p__11393
                 map__11394 (if (seq? map__11394)
                              (apply hash-map map__11394)
                              map__11394)
                 v          (get map__11394 k)]
                v))))
```

So here we can see that the `{v k}` map is in fact first assigned to a local variable `p__11393`. Then the `if` statement tests if that variable is in fact a sequence and turns it into a hash-map if so, otherwise leaves it as it is. Importantly, the value assigned to `k` is looked up in the map *after* all of this happens, thus this works without error (and also would if `:a` wasn't in the map, `get` returns `nil` in that case).

On the other hand macroexpanding the `let` form I get

```
(let*
    [map__11431
  {:a 10}
  map__11431
  (if (seq? map__11431) (apply hash-map map__11431) map__11431)
  v
  (get map__11431 k)
  k
  :a]
  v)
```

and here we can see that `v` gets the result of `(get map__11431 k)`, but `k` isn't defined at this point yet, hence the error.

Comment: now the question is, if such difference has to be considered as a bug or as a feature...

Comment: I would say if one knows that destructuring happens inside the body of the function it is not surprising, hence not a bug. But I think that this fact should maybe be explained better in the appropriate places -- if I remember correctly the Joy of Clojure, for example, doesn't get really get into this.

Comment: what is interesting (but not surprising) that his will not work: (defn myfun­c [{v k} {k :k1}]­ v)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but the following does work:

```
user=> (defn myfunc [{v k} k] v)
#'user/myfunc
user=> (myfunc {:a 10} :a)
10
user=> (let [k :a {v k} {:a 10}] v)
10
user=>
```

Comment: this will of course work, because *k* is defined before anything else